# regex - convert "ｆｏｓｓｉｌ" to "fossil"

Tags: regex, shell

How to convert `ｆｏｓｓｉｌ` to `fossil` with regex?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. See also: [ask]

Comment: Yes, but the downvote party seems a bit ridiculous...

Answer (score 1):

What you actually have in your browser are what are known as full letter Latin lowercase, which is different to `fossil` in standard width.

If this questions is more broadly how do you convert UTF-8 full width to standard ASCII set Latin characters, you would have to do it explicitly as far as I know. I don't know of any library however there may be.

Another thing you could use is add a certain number to the binary encoding, if the full-width encodings are in the same order as the standard character-set.

Character encodings:

```
ｆ - U+FF46
ｏ - U+FF4F
ｓ - U+FF53
ｉ - U+FF49
ｌ - U+FF4C
```

Comment: thank you for sharing what you noticed about the encoding. I didn't realize that until I saw your answer and comment.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
echo 'f o s s i l' | sed 's_ __g'
```

Result will be `fossil`

**Explanation**

`sed` is stream editor. The format `s_<text to replace>_<replacement>_g` tells sed to replace the blank with nothing. In other words, remove the blanks.

If you'd like to use `tr` command, you could do:

```
echo 'f o s s i l' | tr -d "[:blank:]"
```

That'll delete blanks and result in `fossil` also.

**Explanation**

`tr` is translate. `-d` tells translate to remove blanks, which is noted with `[:blank:]`

Comment: What's the magic of `s_ __g`, can you share a link?

Comment: Interesting, do you favor the `'_'` over the `'/'` where no path separator is involved?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah, while `/` is used as the standard separator, I bump into cases where I have to escape slashes and then sed regex looks cryptic. Using underscore as the separator makes it look easier for me to read.

Comment: Key point, that o is not a standard ASCII ''o'', it looks like it will need the extended character set... On further analysis, none of the letters are if copy pasted and converted to byte code.